# Create video from image sequence

Tags: windows-7, video, images

I have sequence of images

```
0001.png
0002.png
...
0230.png
```

I would like to create a video where every image is shown for 0.2 seconds (or maybe some other frame rate). On Mac OS, Quicktime 7 can open the image sequence and I can save it as a *.mov file.

Is there a similar functionality in the Windows Media Player or some other software that is part of the Windows 7 installation? (I am sure that are many third party softwares doing stuff like that, but I would prefer not to install anything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would prefer not to install anything

For some reason, the most recent versions of Movie Maker for Windows Vista and 7 don't have all the features and transitions you can find on earlier builds.

One developer decided to take matters into his own hands and create a portable version of Windows Movie Maker based on Movie Maker 2.1. You can run [**Portable Windows Movie Maker**](http://devrexster.googlepages.com/mmk) on any computer with Windows XP, Vista, or 7. Since it's portable, you can run it from a USB flash drive or a folder on your hard drive without installing it.

[image]

Movie Maker, being a Microsoft product, only supports WMV as output format. If you want MOV, then you'll need a third party application.

Comment: +1 for seeing that part about .MOV file. The correct answer then would be "no, there's no way without installing anything".

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's erm part of the Windows 7 installation package I would say - since it's available as a component of Windows Live Essentials... Windows Live Movie Maker and Windows Live Photo Gallery has this feature.

[Windows Live Essentials](http://download.live.com)

[image]

Comment: erm ... how would you create a 'video sequence' with Live Photo Gallery? AFAIK the output formats are limited to BMP, JPEG (JPG), GIF, PNG and TIFF (TIF).

Comment: On top, Molly dear. See that "Make A Movie" button? (screenshot attached in answer).

Comment: doesn't work without the mighty movie maker though, does it? ^^

Comment: does work with the titanic movie maker though, does it? :) it's an option there... and it makes more sense to bundle that option there (it's crazy trying to ID photos for your video through Movie Maker). SuperUsers I think is not just about which software - it is sometimes about _which way_.

Comment: true enough  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Premiere Elements for that or [VideoSpin](http://www.videospin.com) from Pinnacle.